# Customizing Scanner View

Tags: android, qr-code, barcode-scanner

am using Xzing Scanner View in my Android app.

Used below dependency :

```
implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.8.3'
```

When I run the app and opening up the Scanner, It covers whole Screen.
So, The **Question** is how can I customize my Xzing Scanner View ?

Actually, I have to add a Header or you can say it a Toolbar just above of the Scanner View.

You can look the code below which is there in Scanner Activity :

```
private ZXingScannerView mScannerView = null;
//Here, Seeting layout for Activity (Scanner View).
mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
setContentView(mScannerView);
```

So, It open like below :

[image]

So, To add Header, I have done something like this :

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lprams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(getActivity());
lprams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.rel_header);
mScannerView.setLayoutParams(lprams);
```

But, The result(output) is the Same.
What should I do ? Please, guide. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have Solved it by turning the ScannerActivity into Fragment.
Checkout :

```
 @Nullable
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lprams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(getActivity());
  lprams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.rel_header_one);
  mScannerView.setLayoutParams(lprams);


  if (savedInstanceState != null) {
     mFlash = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(FLASH_STATE, false);
     mAutoFocus = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(AUTO_FOCUS_STATE, true);
     mSelectedIndices = savedInstanceState.getIntegerArrayList(SELECTED_FORMATS);
     mCameraId = savedInstanceState.getInt(CAMERA_ID, -1);
  } else {
     mFlash = false;
     mAutoFocus = true;
     mSelectedIndices = null;
     mCameraId = -1;
  }
  return mScannerView;
 }
```

This is important :  **return mScannerView;**

;)